# Hardware error: CPU, TSC, Processor

Tags: kernel, hardware

Just installed ubuntu 20.04 on a brand new cpu that I had built myself and when I thought I could finally enjoy the OS I got:

```
[Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 ...
[Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ...
[Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0 ...
```

No idea what I got wrong...

I used a i9 processor and Asus z590 motherboard.

Comment: Which Asus board? Could be a bios setting. I have a Rog Strix Z590-e Gaming, I could compare my bios settings to yours. 

There are driver problems with dual monitors with on board graphics and 2.5 ethernet only runs at 1gb at the moment.

Comment: Asus z590a but its a brand new bios so its quite suprising

Comment: I have the brand new bios as well. Wondering if you have secure boot enabled or something weird like that. My install started as 20.04 server so I could setup a Linux Raid 0 array with 2 PCIe 4.0 NVMe drives, then I installed Ubuntu Studio, then removed it's low latency kernel and installed the OEM kernel 20.04b. Later I upgraded to 21.04 and have been playing with various mainline kernels to see if anything besides the OEM kernel will properly enable dual monitors and my NIC. Currently on 5.13.0-051300rc1-generic, which works if I unplug a monitor until I am on the desktop.

Comment: Have you tried switching CSM either on or off in the bios, should be under "boot configuration".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself, turn out that the cpu fan was putting too much pressure on the processor. Also the fan may not have been set in the right direction.